# How to scale same material on two different objects separately without affecting the other?

Tags: materials

Want to use the same material on two objects,but when trying to change the scale of material on one object the other gets also affected.
How can I do it separately.

Comment: make a new material and then copy the nodes from the other one

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use the same material, the most straightforward way would be to use the UV texture space,and give each object a UV map with its own transform (including scale)... but this is a 2D space.. (below)

[image]

[image]

For 3D, you can use the Generated texture space, and manipulating that on the objects, using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> > <kbd>S</kbd> (optionally constraining with<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>). (below)

[image]

Or, you can use the objects' Pass Indices (set in the Object Properties > Relations panel) to discriminate between objects. In the node tree, That number can be picked up using an Object Info node > Object Index, and used any way you like.

Comment: Thank You Robin, but how to use this with PBR materials.

Comment: The texture in the answer governs the color of an emission shader ( Itself  PBR, connected to a material output node in Cycles). The reason I haven't illustrated a full tree is that the scaled textures could be used to govern _any_ aspect of a PBR material.. diffuse color, bump, metalness.. the list goes on.. I might be misunderstanding you.. if you'd like a particular use-case.. go for it.. (maybe edit the OP?).. I'll try to be more specific.